# Get the MYSQL Table Name from ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql

I have a SELECT query which combining three tables. I want to add them to a Jtable by separating the MYSQL tables. I just want to know how can I identify the table name in a Resultset?

```
resultLoad("SELECT sqNum,RegDate,JobNo,DecName,NoOfLines,EntryType,EntrySubType,EntrySubType2,Amount,Status FROM paysheet WHERE  TypeBy='" + cmbStaff.getSelectedItem().toString() + "' AND CommissionStatus='no' UNION SELECT sqNum,RegDate,JobNo,DecName,NoOfLines,EntryType,EntrySubType,EntrySubType2,Amount,Status FROM creditsheet WHERE  TypeBy='" + cmbStaff.getSelectedItem().toString() + "' AND CommissionStatus='no' ORDER BY RegDate UNION SELECT sqNumber,date,JobNumber,DecName,noOfLines,type,type,type,CommissionAmount,status FROM newjobsheet WHERE  TypeBy='" + cmbStaff.getSelectedItem().toString() + "' AND CommissionStatus='no' ORDER BY RegDate");
```

---

```
private void resultLoad(String loadQuery) {

    try {
        Connection c = DB.myConnection();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(loadQuery);

        while (r.next()) {
            Vector v = new Vector();
            v.addElement(r.getString("sqNum"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("RegDate"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("JobNo"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("DecName"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("NoOfLines"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("EntryType") + " - " + r.getString("EntrySubType") + " - " + r.getString("EntrySubType2"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("Amount"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("Status"));
            tm.addRow(v);
            totalComAmount = totalComAmount + Integer.parseInt(r.getString("Amount"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e, "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

I want to add to the Jtable like this by sorting the dates. But the three tables containing different columns.

Answer (score 6):

From your result set, you can get ResultSetMetaData.  It looks like this:

```
rs.getMetaData().getTableName(int Column);
```

Comment: Just be careful about fields which don't have tables.

Comment: In my experience, this method is not reliable. See for instance http://fixunix.com/weblogic/223501-resultsetmetadata-gettablename-int-column-dont-work.html I am not sure what the state is with the latest MySQL driver, but personally I would never rely on this method myself.

Comment: Yes, I tried this. But not working to me. Because it repeating

Comment: @Buck, take a look at ArMed's query. As you can see it is a UNION over paysheet, creditsheet and a few more tables. There is simply no way that any JDBC driver can correctly report the table name, unless the ResultSetMetaData object would somehow be aware of the state of the Resultset (in particular, the current row). To the best of my knowledge, the JDBC spec simply does not address this, and in turn that means vendors are not bound to any particular behavior to handle this. In short, unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to add them to a table by separating the tables."

Not sure what you mean by that, but:

"I just want to know how can I identify the table name in a Resultset?"

the answer is no, not unless you rewrite the query so that it does it for you.

A SELECT statement yields a new (virtual) table - any columns it delivers are technically columns of that new virtual table. The result does not remember the origin of those columns

However, you can write the query so as to give every expression in the SELECT list a column alias that allows you to identify the origin. For instance, you could do:

```
SELECT table1.column1 AS table1_column1
,      table1.column2 AS table1_column2
,      ...
,      table2.column1 AS table2_column1
,      ...
FROM   table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON ... etc
```

If the underscore is not suitable as a separator for your purpose, then you could consider to quote the aliases and pick whatever character as separator you like, including a dot:

```
SELECT table1.column1 AS `table1.column1`
,      ....
etc.
```

UPDATE:

I just noticed your query is a UNION over several tables. Obviously this method won't work in that case. I think your best bet is still to rewrite the query so that it reads:

```
SELECT 'paysheet' as table_name, ...other columns...
FROM   paysheet
UNION
SELECT 'creditsheet', ...other columns...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you want to `SELECT` data from three separate tables and have it returned in one query as one ResultSet, then you want to separate the results back out into individual tables.

*This is completely counter intuitive.*

If you want to have your results separated so that you are able to look at each table's results separately, your best bet is to perform 3 different `SELECT` queries. Basically, what you are asking it to combine 3 things and then separate them again in one pass. Don't do this; if you leave them uncombined in the first place, separating them back out won't be an issue for you.